# HA Proxy in rethinkdb

Tags: haproxy, high-availability, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-ruby

I'm trying to implement HA in rethink-db. Rethink-db documentation seems to be quite short, hence can someone here help in understanding How to we achieve HA in rethink-db?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of HA are you looking for?

I'd first recommend looking [at this article](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sharding-and-replication/#running-a-proxy-node) which explains running a RethinkdB Proxy instance.

You'd want to run this on the same server you are running your application. This proxy instance will intelligent route your query to the correct and available servers. Along with using the [`.wait(...)`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/wait/) command pattern to wait until the table is ready for reads or writes by your application.

Let me know in the comments if there were other things you were looking for!